# .htaccess redirect root domain to sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an interesting .htaccess config on my ROOT that looks like this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    # add a trailing slash if portal-pages/$1 is a directory
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/portal-pages/$1 -d

    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?!portal-pages/)(.*)$ portal-pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

So my real path would be something like this:

```
 local.com/portal-pages/home
```

but the .htaccess translates this path to this:

```
 local.com/home
```

it works great, but if I hit local.com I want it to forward to local.com/home. if I hit local.com/whatever that just goes to /whatever.

How can I do this with this configuration?  Thanks in advance.

also, how can I force everything to https?

Comment: That first rewrite condition does not make any sense at all. What is `$1` meant to be?

Comment: Also the other directives are very strange, like dummies doing nothing at all in a complicated way...

Comment: Can you clarify `if I hit local.com I want it to ONLY redirect to local.com/home if I hit local.com/whatever that just goes to /whatever.` statement?

Comment: Thanks @anubhava this is kind of confusing I'll edit my phrasing. I just want local.com to forward to local.com/home thats all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one additional rule to rewrite landing page to `/home` another redirect rule for `http -> https`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# add a trailing slash if portal-pages/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/portal-pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# forward landing page to /home
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!portal-pages/)(.*)$ portal-pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you.  I think that works but how can I force any page to https?